# Function with arguments swapped

Tags: functions, notation

Let $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

How would you call $g$ with respect to $f$?

That is, if I say $g$ is the _ of $f$, what word goes in the blank?

Comment: Good question! I actually have no idea...

Comment: In computer science reordering the arguments like that would be called flipping.

Comment: Is there any more context, or is $f$ and the domain completely arbitrary? Are you asking for a colloquial term to use repeatedly? A description to clarify the intuition? A standardized term in a certain subfield of math? etc. There are way too many ways I could describe this depending on context and desired effect. e.g. "$g$ is the function whose graph is the reflection of $f$'s about the plane $x=y$", "$g$ is the flip of $f$, meaning $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$", "$g=f\circ\sigma$ (where $\sigma$ is a swap function defined earlier)",...

Comment: @MarkS. I need a way of referring to it in casual conversation. The context I came up with the question is while I needed to point out to a colleague that a certain logical predicate of arity 2 behaved as the (flip? / swap? / mirror?) of another predicate we had defined earlier.